# Remove everything but numbers, the letter x, and the plus sign (Regex, PHP)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Many variations of this question exist, and I tried a few generators, but I can't seem to find a regular expression that matches this. Say I have a phone number that looks like "345-324-3243 X039" I want to remove everything but the digits, the letter x and the plus sign (appears in international numbers).

Here is my current non-working regex and code:

```
$phone = "345-324-3243 X039";
preg_replace('[^\d|x|\+]', '', $phone);
```

I want it to come out to "3453243243X039" but instead I get "30234-2349".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lose the `|` as it is a literal inside a character class, make sure to capture an uppercase "X" (along with a lowercase "x"), use the regex "/quotes/" (otherwise it treats is as "[quotes]") and *use the result*:

```
$phone = "345-324-3243 X039";
$phone = preg_replace('/[^\dxX+]/', '', $phone);
// $phone is 3453243243X039
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `|`s from your regex and escape the `+`.

Comment: The `+` is already escaped, even though it doesn't need to be when inside a character class. You're correct about the `|` being unnecessary, but it shouldn't affect the results for this input.

Answer (score 1):

So you're not only getting residual `-` characters in your results, but entirely different numbers? That's bizarre to me. You can't get `30234-2349` from `345-324-3243 X039` just by deleting characters; the only `0` in that input is right near the end. It's almost like characters are getting shuffled around as well as deleted.

I do notice you don't have regex delimiters around your pattern. I don't even know what the effect of that would be, since I don't recall ever trying it, but that's the only functional problem in your regex. The `|`s inside your character class will be interpreted as literal `|` characters, but that shouldn't affect the results for the sample input you posted.

The code I'd use is this:

```
$phone = preg_replace('/[^\dx+]/i', '', $phone);
```

I've wrapped the regex in `/.../` delimiters, removed the `|`, unescaped the `+` (shouldn't have any effect inside a character class), and made it case-insensitive to catch the capital X.